# Present perfect vs. present question

Tags: tenses, present-perfect

I have been reading *Tonio Korger* by Thomas Mann, translated by David Luke. Here is a sentence about which I have a question:

> He worked in silence, in invisible privacy, for he utterly despised those minor hacks who treated their talent as a social ornament-who, whether they were poor or rich, whether they affected an unkempt and shabby appearance or sumptuous individualistic neck wear, aimed above all else at living happily, charmingly and artistically, little suspecting that good work is brought forth only under the pressure of a bad life, that living and working are incompatible and **that one must have died if one is to be wholly a creator.**

I think it is rather proper that *one must die if one is to be wholly a creator.*
Why the past perfect tense is used in this text?

Comment: Either one would work. It is almost always the case that there are several equally reasonable and semantically indistinguishable ways to say **anything**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quote uses the [*present perfect*](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/present-tense/present-perfect) (have died) to express the concept of something happening in an unspecified time in the past (here, in order for something to follow in time) The present perfect puts here emphasis on the result:

> that one must have died *if one is to be wholly a creator*.

As John Lawler states, things can be stated many ways, and your construction, *one must die if one is to be wholly a creator*, also works, although to my ear, the emphasis on needing to have died before is stronger in Mann's construction. (This parallels the order of events at the beginning of the earlier paragraph:

> But *as his health suffered, so his artistry grew* more refined: it became fastidious, exquisite, rich, subtle, intolerant of banality and hypersensitive in matters of tact...

The suffering precedes the growth.